# Build Error while installing ONNX in Linux

Tags: linux, c++17, onnxruntime, protobuf-c

In order to install OnnX library for linux after cloning the repository.
git clone --recursive https://github.com/Microsoft/onnxruntime

Then ran the build.sh with the following configuration --skip-tests --parallel and --config as Release and also as MinSizeRel

But getting this error:-
error: ‘const class google::protobuf::FieldOptions’ has no member named ‘unverified_lazy’

Tried searching the problem but didn't got any particular resolution to this yet availabe.
Is there some tag I am missing while executing the build.sh ?

The protobuf is already updated.